# Object type remains as LinkedHashMap after assignment

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following JSON data being fetched from an external file source.

```
{
    .... More complicated structures within this JSON format above but I only care about the following
    "feature": {
        "100": {
            "DATA1": [
                {
                    "header": "head1",
                    "someId": "123"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to capture the following portion as List < Data >

```
"DATA1": [
    {
        "header": "head1",
        "someId": "123"
    }
]
```

but unable to do so. Getting following error:

> Cannot cast LinkedHashMap to List.

Method which fetched the data and try to assign it to List< Data >

```
private void getData(){
    AllDataFromFile all = someFetchAPI(); // Got every JSON data in the file. 

    // capturing the portion that I want which I do get. 
    Map<String, Map<String,Object>> feature = all.getFeature(); 
    Map<String, Object> allData = feature.get("100");
    List<Data> dataList = allData.get("DATA1");
}
```

No compilation nor run time errors from above but dataList is not a List of Data.

**Instead it is a List of LinkedHashMap when I see in debug mode. Why? 
And how can I turn this into a List of Data instead?**

Since it doesn't map as a List< Data >, I am unable to perform operations such as follows.

```
dataList.get(0).getHeader().
```

Unable to cast it either and getting same error:

> Cannot cast LinkedHashMap to List.

Please advice. Thanks.

AllDataFromFile class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class AllDataFromFile {
    private Map<String, Map<String,Object>> feature;
}
```

Data class

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Data implements Comparable<Data>, Cloneable{   
    private String header;
    private String someId;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data o) {
        int result = // some logic
        return result;
    }   
}
```

EDIT:

This is data format inside List

```
result = {ArrayList@18590} size = 1
  0 = {LinkedHashMap@18593} size = 2
    "header" -> "header1"
    "someId" -> "id1"
```

Getting following error when I try to match the Object's value to be more specific as follows.

```
private Map<String, Map<String, List<Data>>> feature;
```

Able to go back to getting LinkedHashMap (no use, back to Square one) if I go for the following:

```
private Map<String, Map<String, List>> feature;
```

Error:

> Could not read JSON: Class java.util.LinkedHashMap not subtype of
>   [simple type, class com.a.a.a.a.a.Data] (through reference chain:
>   com.b.b.b.b.b.b.AllDataFromFile["feature"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["100"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["DATA1"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

Comment: Print the `LinkedHashMap`. What does it contain?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It contains my header and someId values.

Comment: Then your JSON doesn't contain an array. It contains a single object value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No is a List. Please see the edited portion in the above post to see the structure. that is the value inside dataList now.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I thought you meant `allData.get("DATA1")` was returning a `LinkedHashMap`. You're saying it's returning a `List<LinkedHashMap>` instead of `List<Data>`. How do you expect Jackson to know it's supposed to deserialize the JSON array to a list of `Data` instances? There's nothing in your class hierarchy that does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson uses reflection to determine what type it needs to deserialize too.

But starting from AllDataFromFile, it cannot determine that the content is actually a List of Data objects, so it falls back to default Lists (ArrayList) and Maps(LinkedHashMap).

I think if you provide more information in the type declaration, jackson might figure it out:

```
public class AllDataFromFile {
    private Map<String, Map<String, List<Data>>> feature;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried your suggestion. It throws an error. If I try with private Map<String, Map<String, List>> feature; it works but no point cos its back to being a LinkedHashMap as expected. 

The error thrown is : Could not read JSON: Class java.util.LinkedHashMap not subtype of [simple type, class com.a.a.a.a.a.Data] (through reference chain: com.b.b.b.b.b.b.AllDataFromFile["feature"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["100"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["DATA1"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]) The fields are definitely matching.

Comment: Ignore above, it works with your solution. Other issue was due to some caching issues. Thank you.